# Excel 'Refresh every x minutes' in Sharepoint

Tags: 2010, list, excel, data-refresh

I have an excel file that have a data connection with sharepoint list.
I want my excel file to be automatically update when something changes on my Sharepoint list. So in excel I choose:

`Data > Connection Properties`

and there I saw option 'Refresh every x minutes` grayed out.

- How can I turn it on?
- Or maybe there is another possibility to auto refresh excel file when item is changed or created on my SharePoint list?

**Edit:** To create my excel file I exported list from my SharePoint site using option: 'Export to Excel' and it created a new excel file with connection

Comment: In Excel's options there should be "Refresh data when opening the file option"-option. Whether this is applicable for you or not, having it enabled disables the "Refresh every x minutes" option.

Comment: 'Refresh data when opening the file option' is disabled. And 'refresh every' is still grayed out

Comment: Which version of Excel you are using - 2010, 2013, 2016?

Comment: My version is 2013

Comment: Please edit your question to provide the specific steps you used to create the data connection. did you use powerpivot? PowerQuery? Or is this an OData connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the bellow steps:: Here i am using Excel 2013

**Step1::** Open new excel file in system.

**Step2::** Choose 'Data' tab -> Choose 'From Other Sources' tab -> choose 'From OData Data feed'

**Step3::** Provide link URL like - site url(your list existed site) + "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc";
EX: https://nagababuSPD.com/TestSite/_vti_bin/listdata.svc

**Step4::** Provide logon credentials(Username, password) and click on Next.

**Step5::** Choose required list from popup and click on Next and click on Finish.

**Step6::** Now we got 'Import Data' pop up, here click on Properties button. Here 'Connection Properties' pop up showing, here check the option 'Refresh Every' and provide required minutes. Click OK and again click OK on 'Import Data' pop up. File filled with SharePoint list data. Here you got extra columns(predefined columns of list). Hide unnecessary columns in excel file and save it.
From now on wards every X minutes(specified refresh time) it's refresh data automatically.

Hope this helps you. If this is helpful to you Up-vote my answer :).

Comment: That helped me to use 'refresh every' option. Thanks :) However now I see that this option refresh file only when it is opened. Is it possible to refresh an excel file that is in SharePoint library without opening it? So I need: excel file on sharepoint site (in library) that will be refreshed automatically  without being opened

Comment: In Office 365 it is possible but in SharePoint 2013 on premise it's not possible directly. Power pivot should be installed on SharePoint Server to refresh excel file in document library. For more info see this blog https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/excel_services__powerpivot_for_sharepoint_support_blog/2015/07/28/excel-services-consuming-a-sharepoint-list-using-the-listdata-svc/

Comment: I guess that using Power pivot for SharePoint is only available for admin of server?

Comment: I guess, for configuration of Power Pivot we need Farm admin credentials, after configuration done, normal SharePoint permissions should work...